# scrollIntoView() method stops scrolling mid-way to the element when triggered by ENTER key on input

Tags: javascript, input, scroll, focus, enter

#### Context

I'm developing a list of items.

I have a form on the top of the list in order to add new items (just 1 input and 1 submit button).

Once the form is submitted, I have the next code in order to automatically scroll into the new element (wherever it fits into the list):

`document.getElementById(newItemId).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });`

For testing purposes and a better understanding of the problem, I created a huge list (50 items) and I made all new items to be placed at the bottom of the list, so I can get clearer evidences.

[image: web page with a form at the top and a list of items below]

#### Problem

When creating the item #51:

- If I **click** the submit button (just a mouse click), **it works** in all browsers (tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge): The item is created at the bottom and the browser scrolls down into the end of the page.

  [image: Web page scrolled at the bottom of the list]
- If I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while the input is focused:

  - **It doesn't work on Chrome**: just stops scrolling like mid-window, no matter the whole page height.

    [image: web page scrolled just like mid-window]
  - **It doesn't work on Edge**: it stops a little before the new item.

    [image: web page scrolled almost at the bottom of the list]
  - **It works on Firefox** properly.

    [image: web page scrolled at the bottom of the list]
- If I tab into the submit button and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it works in all browsers.

**Note**: Without `behavior: "smooth"` there isn't any problem, as it is an instant scroll and there is no time in-between to get interrupted.

**Note 2**: I managed to develop a workaround by using the window.scrollTo() method, but I would like to make it work with scrollIntoView() to avoid pixel-perfect calculations and to report this problem to affected browsers in case this is a bug.

#### Code Example

As suggested by comments, I made this jsbin for testing purposes:
https://jsbin.com/kiwiviboro/edit?html,output

Considerations:

- I made a simplified version, as my app is programmed in TS / React / Next. But the behavior is exactly the same.
- For the simplification, the form doesn't actually create a new element, just scrolls into the last one (the 50th one).
- In this simplified version, you can check that the scroll even doesn't move a single pixel on Chrome nor Edge, as there is no interactions / request in-between.
- I made this after finding the solution, that's why it includes more logic. Please check my solution for details on the logic affected.
- Why did I made it if I already found the solution? Because I would like to discuss about if this is actually the correct behavior or if some browsers have a bug that should be reported and fixed. Please check my solution to find the jsbin with the fixed code to draw your own conclusions

Comment: Could you please post a jsbin etc. link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Source of the problem

I just woke up with fresh ideas! And found out that the problem was in other part of the logic.

I have a logic to **hide the form when it is correctly submitted** (affected CSS property: `visibility: hidden`), so the problem here is that **the input loses the focus "unexpectedly"** and some browsers (Chrome) **when losing the focus stops any scrolling actions** (and maybe other kind of animations?), some others (Edge) notice it a while later and others (Firefox) doesn't even care.

I omitted it as I though it had nothing to do with this problem due to the differences between browsers behaviors.

#### Solution

In case you face this problem, just `.blur()` your input before sending/hiding the form or, most accurately / in any other case, before starting the scroll action, in order to lose the focus manually / intentionally before the scroll starts happening.

#### Code Example

I made the same code example of the question but with the fix already applied:

https://jsbin.com/deciyenivo/edit?html,output

You can check that it now works properly in all browsers.

#### Discussion

Anyway, do you think it is still a bug from Chrome and Edge? (and maybe other browsers) Should I report it?

Or is this considered a correct behavior?

Just for the record, I will leave here my current browsers versions:

- Chrome: 118.0.5993.89 (official build) (64 bits)
- Firefox: 113.0.2 (64-bit)
- Edge: 118.0.2088.61 (official compilation) (64 bits)